# Store an unknown number of vectors into a cell array

Tags: matlab

How to store all the vectors `s` into a cell array, so that I can use it later. the number of vectors `s` is not specific, it depends on the condition `while sigma > sigma_min`. Can anyone help me?

```
A_pinv = A'* inv(A * A');
s  = A_pinv * X
sigma = 2*max(abs(s));
sigma_min = 0.0001;
sigma_decrease_factor = 0.5;

while sigma>sigma_min
    for i = 1:L
        delta = s.*exp(-abs(s).^2/sigma^2);
        s = s - 0.5*delta;
        s = s - A_pinv*(A*s - X);
    end


    sigma = sigma * sigma_decrease_factor;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I think it will work,

```
count = 0;
Data = {};
while sigma>sigma_min
count = count + 1;
     for i = 1:L
         delta = s.*exp(-abs(s).^2/sigma^2);
         s = s - 0.5*delta;
         s = s - A_pinv*(A*s - X);
     end
Data{count} = s;
sigma = sigma * sigma_decrease_factor;
end
```

Comment: the internal L loop, only generate one vector s.

Comment: for one sigma, there is one vector s

Comment: @PeterLi, You mean you want to save `s` outside `for loop`?

Comment: ,Yes, the internal loop is steepest ascent algorithm. So I think only the vector s generated by the outer for loop is counted

Comment: let me put my data in it